# How to get the selected item from a listview by using switch?

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

```
   <ListView Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding TaskList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTask}" >
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell >
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
              <Label Text="{Binding TaskName}" />
              <StackLayout Padding="150,0,0,0">
                <Switch></Switch>
              </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Hello, I am trying to get the selected item from a `ListView` by using switch and could not be sure about how to handle.

Comment: Do you mean the C# `switch` statement, or something else? What's wrong with `SelectedTask` property you already bound it to?

Comment: Sorry that I have forgotten to delete SelectedItem property, the selection should be done only by using switch

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "get the selected item from a listview by using switch". Absolutely no idea at all. You need to explain what that means.

Answer (score 1):

Following example shows how to bind data to switch inside the ListView and how to get toggled data on toggled event:
In xaml:

```
<ListView Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding TaskList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTask}" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell >
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <Label Text="{Binding TaskName}" />
                    <StackLayout Padding="150,0,0,0">
                        <Switch x:Name="chooseItem" VerticalOptions="Center" 
                                IsToggled="{Binding IsToggled, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                Toggled="Switch_Toggled" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

In cs:

```
private void Switch_Toggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var switchItem = (Switch)sender;
        var selectedTask = (SelectedTask)switchItem.BindingContext;
        //here you will get only toggled element model
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```